# Is there a counterpart to the outer product? I.e., divide every term of a vector by every other term of another vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, outer-product

Regarding the dyadic product (specifically, [the outer product or tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Dyadic,_outer,_and_tensor_products)), notated as $\otimes$, can you provide comment on its counterpart? I'm not sure if it has a name, or if it has matrix notation. The operator I am thinking of represents that we divide every term of a vector by every other term of another vector, effectively acting like the division counterpart of the outer product. E.g., if $A =(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ and $B=(b_1, b_2, b_3)$, then
$$C=A ? B = \begin{pmatrix}a_1/b_1 & a_1/b_2 & a_1/b_3 \\ a_2/b_1 & a_2/b_2 & a_2/b_3 \\ a_3/b_1 & a_3/b_2 & a_3/b_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

So, does this operator have a name, e.g., outer quotient or diadic quotient, and does it have a matrix notation? If the tensor (indicial) notation for the outer product is $$C_{ij} = A_i B_j$$ would the tensor notation for the operation I'm asking about be $$C_{ij} = A_i (1/B_j)?$$

Comment: It's still the outer product, just with a different vector.

Comment: @TSF what are the matrix and indicial notations for converting $B$ to $B' = (1/b_1, 1/b_2, 1/b_3)$?

Comment: Hadamard division, $B' = 1_n \oslash B$. You can represent the vector of all $1$s in different ways, like with \mathbb or \mathds as well.

Comment: @TSF Ah, OK, so for the matrix notation we have $C=A\otimes(1_3 \oslash B)$ and for the indicial notation we have $C_{ij}=A_i (1/B_j)$?